# Getting values from a chart

Tags: geometry

I have a chart which looks like so:

[image]

One needs to choose one of three types (1,2,3), then according to "a" value (horizontal axis of the chart) to go up until the type of the curve it has chosen, and from there, horizontally to the left and read the value "b" on the vertical axis.

For example if one chooses "type 3"(yellow line) and b = 50 -> this means that a is approximately a = 0.475

[image]

How can I define all this relations in one (or three for each of three types(lines)) equation? I added the angles each type(line) closes with horizontal axis.

Thank you for the reply.

EDIT: I do not have the equations of the lines.

Comment: Do you have the equations of the lines? Could you get them easily?

Comment: No I do not have the equations of the lines. Is there a way to get them by using their angles and lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a point on a line, say $(x_0,y_0)$ and let $\theta$ be the angle of the line.
 Then $y = \tan(\theta)(x-x_0) + y_0$ is the equation for that line.

For example, $y = -\tan(12)(x-50) + 0.475$ is the equation of type 3.

Comment: Thank you rackne. But I do not understand how can I use this y = tan(12)*(x-50)+0.475 equation of the type3 to get "b" value for given "a" value.

Comment: think it like b = tan(12)(a-50) + 0.475. if a = 10, then b = tan(12)(10-50)+0.475

Comment: By reading "b" directly from the graph for a = 10 and type3, I got: b = 0.52
By using your equation I got -8.03

Comment: There should be a minus before tan(12), I fixed it. You say that for a = 50, b is approximately 0.475 actually it should be precise to have derive an equation.

Comment: For b = −tan(12)(10−50)+0.475, I am getting 8.98, not 0.52 as read from the chart.

Comment: I think I understand what is the issue. It should not be multiplied with tangent but rather the slope:
slope =(0.475-0.53)/(50-0) = -0.0011; 
b = -0.0011*a+0.475

Comment: yeah but tangent should give you slope, then there might be an issue with the angle so. anyway you solved your problem.

Comment: The 12 degrees angle is correct, and I checked all three of them.
Thank you for the answers.